# Javascript module pattern issue

Tags: javascript

I have this module

```
var MF = (function() { // module pattern start
    function MF(selector) {
        if (!(this instanceof MF))
            return new MF(selector); // always construct
        this.node = null; // expose your DO
        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            switch (selector.substring(0, 1)) {
                case '#':
                    this.node = document.getElementById(selector.substring(1));
                    break;
                case '.':
                    this.node = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.substring(1).replace('.', ' '));
                    break;
                default :
                    this.node = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
                    break;
            }
            if (this.node.length > 1) {
                return MFList(this.node);
            } else if (typeof this.node.length !== 'undefined') {
                return MF(this.node[0]);
            }
        } else if (selector instanceof HTMLElement) {
            this.node = selector;
        }
    }
    function isArraylike(obj) {
        var length = obj.length;
        return (length === 0 || typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (length - 1) in obj);
    }
    function MFList(List) {
        var _List = [];
        MF.foreach(List, function(k, v) {
            _List[k] = new MF(v);
        });
        return _List.length > 0 ? _List : false;
    };

    MF.prototype.foreach = function(obj, callback) {
        var value,
                i = 0,
                isArray = isArraylike(obj);

        if (isArray) {
            var length = obj.length;
            for (; i < length; i++) {
                value = callback.call(obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ]);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (i in obj) {
                value = callback.call(obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ]);

                if (value === false) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
    return MF; // pass refence out
}()); // module pattern end
```

I have to admit, javascript's object model is quite confusing for me. The error I'm getting is that it doesn't recognize `MF.foreach` in function `MFList`. I'm not quite aware of how instances work with this module pattern but I'd be really glad if someone could tell me how I can call `MF.foreach` inside a private function of the object? Thanks!

Comment: `MF.prototype = {}; // set up any inheritance` Don't do that. The function will *already* have a blank object on its `prototype` property, that line is at best a no-op.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, I have no idea why I left it there, thanks!

Comment: You need an instance of `MF` to use its `forEach` method. Try `MF().foreach` or attach the function to the constructor.

Comment: @elclanrs I see now, so I guess my best option would be to make it static.

Comment: Yes, if it needs to be public but it's not related to the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The error I'm getting is that it doesn't recognize `MF.foreach` in function `MFList`.

Right. The function `MF` doesn't have a property called `foreach`. Objects *created* via the function `MF` have a property called `foreach` (they get it from the prototype they're assigned via the `new` operator when you do `new MF(...)`).

If you wanted `MF` itself to have that function instead of objects created by it having that function, you'd change

```
MF.prototype.foreach = ...
```

to

```
MF.foreach = ....
```

`MF.prototype` is used to set the prototype of objects created via `new MF`; the properties you put there have no other connection to the `MF` function.

---

Side note: I would strongly recommend refactoring the `MF` function. You're using it as a constructor function, but *sometimes* it returns objects using the object `MF.prototype` as their prototype, *other* times it returns arrays. That kind of inconsistency is a bad idea. When a function is designed to be called via `new` (e.g., it's a *constructor* function), the normal case is that it doesn't return anything; the result of the `new FunctionName` expression will be the object created via `new`. But if the constructor function returns a non-`null` object (such as when you're returning an array), that overrides the normal result of the `new` expression.

Comment: About the side note, I'm not instancing this object ( or at least I think I'm not ). Basically how I use it is much like `jQuery` - `MF('#selector')`. I never use `new MF()`. Basically I don't really know what I'm doing but as long as it works I stick with it `:D`

Comment: @php_nub_qq: You're *always* using `new MF`. :-) Look at the first two lines of the function. Those ensure that if you do `MF('#selector')` it just turns around and does `new MF('#selector')`. If you don't need it to be a constructor function, I'd remove those lines and just new a local variable `node` rather than `this.node`.